# Simulating dynamic polymorphism in C

Tags: c, polymorphism

This code snippet is a research attempt to find means for dealing with dynamic polymorphism (in C): two or more related "classes" share a common interface. Here is my best shot:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CALL(INTERFACE_PTR, METHOD_NAME, ...) \
INTERFACE_PTR->METHOD_NAME(INTERFACE_PTR->object, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define DESTRUCT(INTERFACE_PTR) INTERFACE_PTR->destruct(INTERFACE_PTR->object)

/*******************************************************************************
* Dummy data structures used for the demonstration.                            *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct int_triple {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} int_triple;

typedef struct int_pointer_triple {
    int* a;
    int* b;
    int* c;
} int_pointer_triple;

void int_triple_init(int_triple* it)
{
    it->a = 0;
    it->b = 0;
    it->c = 0;
}

void int_pointer_triple_init(int_pointer_triple* ipt)
{
    ipt->a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    ipt->b = malloc(sizeof(int));
    ipt->c = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *ipt->a = 0;
    *ipt->b = 0;
    *ipt->c = 0;
}

void int_triple_set(void* int_triple_ptr, int a, int b, int c)
{
    int_triple* it = (int_triple*) int_triple_ptr;

    it->a = a;
    it->b = b;
    it->c = c;

    printf("int_triple_set(%d, %d, %d)\n", a, b, c);
}

void int_pointer_triple_set(void* int_triple_pointer_ptr, int a, int b, int c)
{
    int_pointer_triple* ipt = (int_pointer_triple*) int_triple_pointer_ptr;

    *ipt->a = a;
    *ipt->b = b;
    *ipt->c = c;

    printf("int_pointer_triple_set(%d, %d, %d)\n", a, b, c);
}

int int_triple_get_sum(void* int_triple_ptr)
{
    int_triple* it = (int_triple*) int_triple_ptr;
    puts("int_triple_get_sum()");
    return it->a + it->b + it->c;
}

int int_pointer_triple_get_sum(void* int_pointer_triple_ptr)
{
    int_pointer_triple* ipt = (int_pointer_triple*) int_pointer_triple_ptr;
    puts("int_pointer_triple_get_sum()");
    return *ipt->a + *ipt->b + *ipt->c;
}

int int_triple_get_product(void* int_triple_ptr)
{
    int_triple* it = (int_triple*) int_triple_ptr;
    puts("int_triple_get_product()");
    return it->a * it->b * it->c;
}

int int_pointer_triple_get_product(void* int_pointer_triple_ptr)
{
    int_pointer_triple* ipt = (int_pointer_triple*) int_pointer_triple_ptr;
    puts("int_pointer_triple_get_product()");
    return *ipt->a * *ipt->b * *ipt->c;
}

void int_triple_destruct(void* int_triple_ptr)
{
    free(int_triple_ptr);
    puts("int_triple_destruct()");
}

void int_pointer_triple_destruct(void* int_pointer_triple_ptr)
{
    int_pointer_triple* ipt = (int_pointer_triple*) int_pointer_triple_ptr;
    free(ipt->a);
    free(ipt->b);
    free(ipt->c);
    free(ipt);
    puts("int_pointer_triple_destruct");
}

/*******************************************************************************
* Interface stuff.                                                             *
*******************************************************************************/
typedef struct int_triple_interface {
    void*  object;
    void  (*set)         (void*, int, int, int);
    int   (*get_sum)     (void*);
    int   (*get_product) (void*);
    void  (*destruct)    (void*);
} int_triple_interface;

int_triple_interface* new_int_triple()
{
    int_triple_interface* interface = malloc(sizeof(*interface));
    int_triple* it = malloc(sizeof(*it));
    int_triple_init(it);

    interface->object      = it;
    interface->set         = int_triple_set;
    interface->get_sum     = int_triple_get_sum;
    interface->get_product = int_triple_get_product;
    interface->destruct    = int_triple_destruct;

    return interface;
}

int_triple_interface* new_int_pointer_triple()
{
    int_triple_interface* interface = malloc(sizeof(*interface));
    int_pointer_triple* ipt = malloc(sizeof(*ipt));
    int_pointer_triple_init(ipt);

    interface->object      = ipt;
    interface->set         = int_pointer_triple_set;
    interface->get_sum     = int_pointer_triple_get_sum;
    interface->get_product = int_pointer_triple_get_product;
    interface->destruct    = int_pointer_triple_destruct;

    return interface;
}

int main() {
    int_triple_interface* interface;
    int sum;
    int product;

    puts("--- int_triple ---");

    interface = new_int_triple();
    CALL(interface, set, 2, 3, 4);
    sum = CALL(interface, get_sum);
    product = CALL(interface, get_product);
    DESTRUCT(interface);

    printf("sum = %d, product = %d.\n", sum, product);

    puts("\n--- int_pointer_triple ---");

    interface = new_int_pointer_triple();

    CALL(interface, set, 5, 6, 7);
    sum = CALL(interface, get_sum);
    product = CALL(interface, get_product);
    DESTRUCT(interface);

    printf("sum = %d, product = %d.\n", sum, product);
}
```

The output from the **`main`** is as follows:

> ```
> --- int_triple ---
> int_triple_set(2, 3, 4)
> int_triple_get_sum()
> int_triple_get_product()
> int_triple_destruct()
> sum = 9, product = 24.
>
> --- int_pointer_triple ---
> int_pointer_triple_set(5, 6, 7)
> int_pointer_triple_get_sum()
> int_pointer_triple_get_product()
> int_pointer_triple_destruct
> sum = 18, product = 210.
> ```

**Critique request**

I would like to hear comments on:

1. naming conventions,
2. coding conventions,
3. overall comments,
4. design pattern,
5. anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your approach has at least two unfortunate aspects:

- Your approach to `interface->object` uses an extra heap-allocation.
- Adding a new "method" to `int_triple_interface` requires increasing the size of every "int triple" "object" in the program by `sizeof(void(*)())`.
- Nit: Your `DESTRUCT(x)` macro doesn't actually `free(x)`.

The first problem could be solved by allocating the "object data" directly after the "interface data", with allowances for alignment/padding:

```
void int_triple_destruct(void* int_triple_ptr)
{
    puts("int_triple_destruct() is now a no-op");
}

int_triple_interface* new_int_triple()
{
    int_triple_interface* interface = malloc(sizeof(*interface) + sizeof(int_triple));
    int_triple* it = (void*)(interface + 1);
    int_triple_init(it);

    interface->object      = it;
    interface->set         = int_triple_set;
    interface->get_sum     = int_triple_get_sum;
    interface->get_product = int_triple_get_product;
    interface->destruct    = int_triple_destruct;

    return interface;
}
```

The second problem could be solved by storing all your function pointers away in a static data table: one table per *object type*, instead of one table per *object instance*.

```
#define CALL(INTERFACE_PTR, METHOD_NAME, ...) \
INTERFACE_PTR->vtable->METHOD_NAME(INTERFACE_PTR->object, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define DESTRUCT(INTERFACE_PTR) INTERFACE_PTR->vtable->destruct(INTERFACE_PTR->object)

typedef struct {
    void  (*set)         (void*, int, int, int);
    int   (*get_sum)     (void*);
    int   (*get_product) (void*);
    void  (*destruct)    (void*);
} int_triple_vtable_t;

int_triple_vtable_t int_triple_vtable = {
    int_triple_set,
    int_triple_get_sum,
    int_triple_get_product,
    int_triple_destruct,
};

typedef struct {
    void* object;
    int_triple_vtable_t* vtable;
} int_triple_interface;

int_triple_interface* new_int_triple()
{
    int_triple_interface* interface = malloc(sizeof(*interface) + sizeof(int_triple));
    int_triple* it = (void*)(interface + 1);
    int_triple_init(it);

    interface->object = it;
    interface->vtable = int_triple_vtable;

    return interface;
}
```

You probably don't really need the `object` pointer at all (since now it just points to `(char *)interface + k` for some known offset `k`), but I haven't thought about it too much.

---

In general, the question "how do I do OOP in C" can be answered by looking at what C++ does and then slavishly copying it. That's where I got the idea of "vtables" here, for example. Your `object` pointer is roughly equivalent to a C++ "virtual base class". And if you really want to do efficient, type-safe OOP in C, you're eventually going to have to reckon with the concepts of "copy construction" and "move construction", both of which you can find implemented in C++.